# Cannot read property 'suppressHydrationWarning' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm a react beginner, currently learning NextJS.

I've created a simple component in `CreateSubject.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function CreateSubject(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Name</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            ref="input"
            className="input"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field is-grouped is-grouped-right">
        <p className="control">
          <a
            className="button is-primary"
            onClick={props.onClick}
          >
            Validate
          </a>
        </p>
        <p className="control">
          <a className="button is-light">
            Cancel
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
```

This code is NOT working, I got the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'suppressHydrationWarning' of null`

If I change this function into a Component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class CreateSubject extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="field">
...
```

it's working well. What is wrong with the first code?

For more information, I'm using NextJS, and `CreateSubject` is called like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Modal from './Modal';
import CreateSubject from './forms/CreateSubject';


let displayShowModal = false;
const createSubject = () => {
  alert('okkkk')
};
export default () => (
  <div>
    <Modal display={displayShowModal} title="Creating subject">
      <CreateSubject onClick={createSubject}/>
    </Modal>
    <Navbar/>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: There are few React libraries that doesn't work if used inside SFC instead of a class. AFAIK it's related with refs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kinduser, unfortunately all examples on NextJS website are using SFC instead of a class. So it should be working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was due to the input field having a `ref` attribute. Removing the `ref` attribute that wasn't that useful anyway fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you used a functional component and we should use useRef for it: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components. Also, be cautious when you pass ref attribute to your element. Often people pass name of the ref as a string instead of using {}.

In your case it should be:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

export default function CreateSubject(props) {
  const anyName = useRef(null);
...
  <input
    ref={anyName} // not ref="anyName"
    className="input"
    type="text"
   />
...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ref` attribute in the input tag. If you really need to use it, use useRef as an {object}, not as a "String".

I ran into the same issue today at work!